# pushAndRemoveUntil is not working with onGenerateRoute in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-null-safety, flutter-navigation

pushAndRemoveUntil is not proper working with "onGenerateRoute" in MaterialApp but if I have used pushAndRemoveUntil the "routes" in MaterialApp So it's working fine.

current screen name is FiveScreen. and here is the one button and below code in for onclick.

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context)=>ThirdScreen()), ModalRoute.withName(MUtils.second));
```

if I have use the "routes" in MaterialApp So it's navigate to "SecondScreen" after onbackpress to navigate to "FirstScreen" but If I have Use the the "onGenerateRoute" in MaterialApp so it's redirect to "secondScreen" but after click on the backpress so App is closed.
Thank you in advance.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  /*routes: {
    MUtils.home: (context) => HomeScreen(),
    MUtils.second: (context) => SecondScreen(),
    MUtils.thirdScreen: (context) => ThirdScreen(),
    MUtils.fourth: (context) => FourthScreen(),
    MUtils.settings: (context) => SettingsScreen(),
  },*/
   onGenerateRoute:MyRoutes().onGenerateRoute,
  //home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);}
```

Below is onGenerate Route class

```
class MyRoutes{
Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
switch (settings.name) {
  case '/':
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => MyHomePage(
        title: "Home Screen",
      ),
    );
  case MUtils.home:
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => HomeScreen(content: settings.arguments,),
    );
  case MUtils.second:
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => SecondScreen(

      ),
    );case MUtils.thirdScreen:
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => ThirdScreen(

      ),
    );
  case MUtils.fourth:
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => FourthScreen(

      ),
    );
  case MUtils.settings:
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => SettingsScreen(),
    );
  default:
    return null;
}
```

}
}

I have draw design to better understand.

***Route*:- HomeScreen=> 1_Screen=> 2_Screen=> 3_Screen=> 4_Screen=> 5_Screen (Now Navigate to)  2_Screen (onBackPress)=> 1_Screen (onBackPress)=> HomeScreen.**

***onGenerateRoute*:- HomeScreen=> 1_Screen=> 2_Screen=> 3_Screen=> 4_Screen=> 5_Screen (Now Navigate to)  2_Screen (onBackPress)=> App Closed.**

So here issue the issue in "onGenerateRoute" when backpress in 2_screen to app is closed but it's working in "Routes".

Comment: post the code to reproduce your issue

Comment: @pskink Please check again i have update the question and added the code. in above code right now I have comment the "routes" code and use the "onGenerateRoute" in MaterialApp.

Comment: @pskink I have draw some architecture So You can better understand about the issue. and thank you for the response.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the your code and you are redirecting to initial screen.
 Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('0', ModalRoute.withName('0'));
But I want to redirect to another screen.

Comment: so change '0' with something else

Comment: I have did but not working, Can you please try my code?

Comment: see `main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(
initialRoute: '/',
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
final map = {
'/': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5
};
return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (ctx) => FooPage(map[settings.name]!), settings: settings);
},
));
}`

Comment: Thank bro. Your code is working now as per my requirement. but can you please let me know  why my code is not working because we have done some thing only deference is you have directly onGenerateRoute and i have create the class for this.

Comment: Can you please try with my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242327/discussion-between-alpit-panchal-and-pskink).

Answer (score -1):

Mycode

```
onGenerateRoute: (setting){
    Widget myroute = Container(

    );
    if(setting.name == '/'){
      myroute =   MyHomePage(
        title: "Home Screen",
      );
    }else if(setting.name == MUtils.home){
      myroute =   HomeScreen();
    }else if(setting.name == MUtils.second){
      myroute =   SecondScreen();
    }else if(setting.name == MUtils.thirdScreen){
      myroute =   ThirdScreen();
    }else if(setting.name == MUtils.fourth){
      myroute =   FourthScreen();
    }else if(setting.name == MUtils.settings){
      myroute =   SettingsScreen();
    }
   return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => myroute,
    );
  },
```

Your Code:-

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  final map = {'/': 1, '1': 2, '2': 3, '3': 4, '4': 5,'5':6};
  return MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (ctx) => FooPage(map[settings.name]!),
    settings: settings, // <<< this is the difference
  );
},
```

Only the deference is here but I couldn't find the issue in my code.